# Levenshtein distance in a file

Tags: python

The statement says:

Modify the above program so that given the GGCCTTGCCATTGG pattern, each of the first 10 lines of the previous file indicates:

· The distance of edition that finds the substring more similar of that line.

· The substrings of that line that finds to minimum distance of edition

The above program is this:

```
import time

def levenshtein_distance (first, second):
    if len(first) > len(second):
        first, second = second, first
    if len(second) == 0:
        return len(fist)
    first_length = len(first) + 1
    second_length = len(second) + 1
    distance_matrix = [[0]*second_length for x in range(first_length)]
    for i in range(first_length): distance_matrix[i][0] = i
    for j in range(second_length): distance_matrix[0][j] = j
    for i in xrange(1, first_length):
        for j in range(1, second_length):
            deletion = distance_matrix[i-1][j] + 1
            insertion = distance_matrix[i][j-1] + 2
            substitution = distance_matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1
            if first[i-1] != second[j-1]:
                substitution += 1
            distance_matrix[i][j] = min(insertion, deletion, substitution)
    return distance_matrix[first_length-1][second_length-1]

def dna(patro):
    t1 = time.clock()
    f = open("HUMAN-DNA.txt")
    text = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    distanciaMin = 100000000 
    distanciaPosicion = 0
    distanciaLinea = 0
    distanciaSubstring = ""
    numeroLinea = 0
    for line in text:
        numeroLinea = numeroLinea + 1
        for i in range(len(line)-len(patro)):
            cadena = line[i:i+len(patro)]
            distancia = levenshtein_distance(cadena, patro)
            if distancia < distanciaMin:
                distanciaMin = distancia
                distanciaPosicion = 1
                distanciaLinea = numeroLinea
                distanciaSubstring = cadena

    t2 = time.clock()
```

Now i put the new pattern

```
dna("GGCCTTGCCATTGG")
```

I have the distance of edition that is distanciaMin and I'm not sure about result of distanciaSubstring that is the substrings of that line(second point of statement), my question is How can i count the first ten lines in the text?

A part of the file is:

```
CCCATCTCTTTCTCATTCCTTGGTTGAGAACACGAACTTCAGGACTTGCCTCACACTAGGGCCCATTCTT
TGTTTCCCAGAAAGAAGAGGCTCTCCACACAGAGTCCCATGTACACCAGGCTGTCAACAAACATGAATTG
AATGAAGGAGTGGATGGTTGGGTGGAAGTGATTTAAGAAATCCTAACTGGGGAATTTCACTGGAAACTTA
GGAAATTCAATTTATATAAAGTCTATGAATCGTCCATTTTTGTGTCCGCACATTCAAATGCTGTAGCTAA
TTTCCTGCTAAACAGTAGAAATTCAGTAAGTGTTCATGTTGAAAGGATGAAATTTGAGTGCTCTTGCATC
CTCAAAGAACTCTAGTAAAATAGAAATAAAGCTTTATTTGGAAGATTAAGTCATGAGCATAATTATGAGA
AGGCGGTCATTCTAATAATAGTGTCTTCACAAGTAGATGCTACATGCTGTGTAATATTTTGACTAAAAAA
AGTTCCTCTCAACATTTCTGAAGTGAGATAATGTACAACGATCCATGTTTTTAGCTACCTTGATAAGTTT
AGTGCATCCAGGGCTCCTTTCTTACCTGCTAACCGCCGAGTTTCAAATGCTAAGAAATTCTTCATTTCCT
AACACAAATATTCAATATAATTGCTGGTTGTTTGGGAGAAGAAAAATTTAGAATTCAGAAAGAAATACAG
AATGAAATGTTCTAATCAATCGAAAAAGGATTCTATAGACTTCGACGTTGTCTGGTTTACAAAGCAGTCT
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't understand your full question. But I am trying to solve `How can i count the first ten lines in the text?`. You can use filehandler.readlines(). It will load files in memory as a list where each row is separated by new line character.
Then you can read 10 lines from the list. You can try something like this,

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # read file as a list of lines (a)
>>> def line(a, jump=2): # keep jump = 10 for your requirement.
    lines = len(a)
    i = 0
    while i < lines+1:
        yield a[i:i+jump]
        i += jump
>>> foo = line(a)
>>> foo.next()
[0, 1]
>>> foo.next()
[2, 3]
>>> foo.next()
[4, 5]
```

For your code it will be,

```
foo = line(text, 10)
foo.next() # should return you 10 elements in each call
```

Comment: why down vote? What is wrong with my explanation. Please justify your down vote.

Comment: i try with while but always gives me error, therefore i ask how i do

Comment: You code looks fine. Does it run for values NOT from file? I assume something is wrong in interpretation of value (lines) from file. Can you post sample caontent as they exist in file.?

Comment: and in my code how can i put this for only read the first ten lines?

Comment: you want see the file HUMAN-DNA.txt?

Comment: Yes. Just sample values.

Comment: How can i upload a file?

Comment: As i guessed you are trying to find levenshtein distance between string and list of string. In your code, add `cadena = ''.join(cadena )` AFTER `cadena = line[i:i+len(patro)]`

Comment: I push this but you are sure that is for first ten lines?

Comment: I feel your code is correct to read first 10 lines. But problem is while calculating `distancia = levenshtein_distance(cadena, patro)`. `cadena` is a list of string. You need to convert list of string into a string. Then you will get correct levenshtein_distance. Why don't you try and check?

Comment: You can also visualize your code at `http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html`. It is very useful to understand your code.

Comment: i check with my code and i obtain the same result with your code added

Comment: What is expected ans and program answer.?

Comment: The answer of the program is: The pattern "GGCCTTGCCATTGG" finds at  line 63 i the minium distance of eddition is 17. The substring more similar is GCCTGGCCTATTTG. But the answer is wrong because the line is 63 and i want read only the first 10 lines.

Comment: Ok. Your code is just reading 10 chars for each line from file. I was wrong with getting list of string. Also to read 10 lines in each call my function is sufficient.

Comment: So how can i do this?